# UML assignment question

Tags: uml

Sorry, I know this is a very lame question to ask and not of any use to anyone else. I have an assignment in UML due tomorrow and I don't even know the basics (all-nighter ahead!). I'm not looking for a walkthrough, I simply want your opinion on something. The assignment is as follows (you only need to skim over it!):

=============

Gourmet Surprise (GS) is a small catering firm with five employees. During a typical weekend, GS caters fifteen events with twenty to fifty people each. The business has grown rapidly over the past year and the owner wants to install a new computer system for managing the ordering and buying process. GS has a set of ten standard menus. When potential customers call, the receptionist describes the menus to them. If the customer decides to book an event (dinner, lunch, picnic, finger food etc.), the receptionist records the customer information (e.g., name, address, phone number, etc.) and the information about the event (e.g., place, date, time, which one of the standard menus, total price) on a contract. The customer is then faxed a copy of the contract and must sign and return it along with a deposit (often a credit card or by check) before the event is officially booked. The remaining money is collected when the catering is delivered. Sometimes, the customer wants something special (e.g., birthday cake). In this case, the receptionist takes the information and gives it to the owner who determines the cost; the receptionist then calls the customer back with the price information. Sometimes the customer accepts the price, other times, the customer requests some changes that have to go back to the owner for a new cost estimate. Each week, the owner looks through the events scheduled for that weekend and orders the supplies (e.g., plates) and food (e.g., bread, chicken) needed to make them. The owner would like to use the system for marketing as well. It should be able to track how customers learned about GS, and identify repeat customers, so that GS can mail special offers to them. The owner also wants to track the events on which GS sent a contract, but the customer never signed the contract and actually booked a GS.

Exercise:
Create an activity diagram and a use case model (complete with a set of detail use case descriptions) for the above system. Produce an initial domain model (class diagram) based on these descriptions.
Elaborate the use cases into sequence diagrams, and include any state diagrams necessary. Finally use the information from these dynamic models to expand the domain model into a full application model.

=============

In your opinion, do you think this question is asking me to come up with a package for an online ordering system to replace the system described above, or to create UML diagrams that facilitate the existing telephone-based system?

Comment: A nice book to get up to speed fast with UML is "UML distilled", by Fowler - short and very clear...

Comment: It's the morning after. :) Did you get it done?

Comment: @sgreeve, I made a pretty good attempt. Amazing what you can learn in one night when you really need to :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Create an activity diagram and a use case model (complete with a set of detail use case descriptions) **for the above system.**

I think it's right there in the text: they want you to document the system described.

Best of luck!

Comment: Silly me, I'm a bit sleep deprived at the moment. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem. It truly will be an all-nighter: caffeine time. :)